# How to check condition before INSERT with SQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a data_type table and a data table. The column structure is as follows:

```
data_type    data
=========    ====================
id | Type    Type_ID | data_count
---------    --------------------
 1 | a             1 | 50
 2 | b             2 | 100
 3 | c             3 | 30
```

When adding a new row to a datatable, I want to set a different limit on the number of data_ that can be entered based on the type_id.

For example, type a can only contain integers between 50 and 100. I want to be able to type 0 to 100 for type b and 10 to 30 for type c.

Outside this range, an error response (400) is returned.

Is there a way to do it with SQL, without using an ORM? For reference, below is my current code.

DAO.js

```
const createRecordData = async (userId, a1, a2, typeId, count) => {
  await myDataSource.query(
    `INSERT INTO a (user_id,a1,a2)
  VALUES (?,?,?)`,
    [userId, a1, a2]
  );

  const datas = await myDataSource.query(
    `INSERT INTO data (a_id,typeId,count)
  VALUES ((SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()),?,?)`,
    [typeId, count]
  );
  return datas;
};
```

=====
I've tried the following.

DAO.js

```
const createRecordData = async (userId, a1, a2, typeId, count) => {
  await myDataSource.query(
    `INSERT INTO a (user_id,a1,a2)
  VALUES (?,?,?)`,
    [userId, a1, a2]
  );

  await myDataSource.query(`
  DELIMITER $$
  CREATE TRIGGER checkValueTBL 
  BEFORE INSERT ON data FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.data_type = 1 THEN
      IF NEW.data < 10 OR NEW.data > 90 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45015' 
        SET message_text = 'Type a: value not between 10 and 90';
    END IF;
    ELSEIF NEW.data_type = 2 THEN
      IF NEW.data < 30 OR NEW.data > 50 THEN
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45015' 
      SET message_text = 'Type a: value not between 30 and 50';
    END IF;
    ELSEIF NEW.data_type = 3 THEN
      IF NEW.data < 60 OR NEW.data > 200 THEN
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45015' 
      SET message_text = 'Type a: value not between 60 and 200';
    END IF;
  END $$
  DELIMITER ;`);

  const datas = await myDataSource.query(
    `INSERT INTO data (a_id,typeId,count)
  VALUES ((SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()),?,?)`,
    [typeId, count]
  );
  return datas;
};
```

If you write the above, you will get the following error.

```
     "err": "ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$\n CREATE TRIGGER checkValueTBL \n BEFORE INSERT ON TBL FOR EACH ROW' at line 1"
```

What am I doing wrong? I need help

Comment: *Is there a way to do it with SQL* Yes, in BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE trigger. But you must alter `data` table - it must store both lower and upper values limits (or. for example, lower boundary and amount). *Outside this range, an error response (400) is returned.* No such error code in MySQL.

Comment: I added the code that tried to trigger. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please synchronize names and values over the whole question. For example, `.. BEFORE INSERT ON TBL FOR EACH ROW ..` - no such table in your description.

Comment: I have Synchronized with the text

Answer (score 0):

Possible realization:

```
CREATE TABLE types (
  type_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  type_name VARCHAR(255)
  );
CREATE TABLE types_data (
  type_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  type_amount INT
  );
CREATE TABLE types_limits (
  type_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  amount_from INT,
  amount_till INT
);
INSERT INTO types VALUES (1, 'Type A'), (2, 'Type B'), (3, 'Type C');
INSERT INTO types_limits VALUES (1, 10, 100), (2, 20, 50), (3, 50, 100);
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_check_limitations
BEFORE INSERT ON types_data
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                  FROM types_limits
                  WHERE type_id = NEW.type_id
                    AND NEW.type_amount BETWEEN amount_from AND amount_till
                  ) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45015' 
      SET message_text = 'The entered amount is out of the allowed range.' ;
  END IF;
END
```

```
INSERT INTO types_data VALUES (1, 75);
```

```
INSERT INTO types_data VALUES (2, 75);
```

> ```
> The entered amount is out of the allowed range.
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VgH5CJGr)

Comment: After trying the method you told me, it worked.
But when I tried again, I got this error "ER_TRG_ALREADY_EXISTS: Trigger already exists".
Do you by any chance know the cause of this error?

Comment: @ggyoE Trigger is created ONCE! And after this creation it works until you drop it.